# How to get ALL posts and statuses from a facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, parsing, social-media, mining

In IPython, I do

```
urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/18888909708/posts?access_token=my_access_token').read()
```

but it returns posts going back only one month.

How do I get posts going back, if not to the creation of the page, as far as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The Facebook Social Graph API has a `since()` and `until()` option.

For instance, you can grab posts in between two dates like so

```
access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
fanpage = 'taylorswift'
startDate = '02/02/12'
endDate = '02/02/14'
url = https://graph.facebook.com/'fanpage'?fields=posts.limit(500).since('startDate').until('endDate').fields(message)&access_token=%s' % (access_token)
```

Then it'll return a json file that can be cleaned up and analyzed.